# RegEx to allow only and only digits

Tags: regex, angular, typescript, input

I am writing a RegEx to use on input fields. The purpose of this is letting  user enter **only digits** and nothing else (even dot and comma are disallowed).
Here is my code so far:

```
RegExp = new RegExp(/^[0-9]$/);
```

This however still lets the user type in dots and commas.
Which change I should make to get only digits?

Comment: How are you applying the regex? show the HTML (or more JS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `type = "number"` to allow only digits and `onkeypress` event to filter `dot` sign for your `input` control:

```
<input type="number"
   (onkeypress)="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0 || 
   event.charCode == 13) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57">
```

[As MDN says:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number)

> elements of type number are used to let the user enter a
>   number. They include built-in validation to reject non-numerical
>   entries. The browser may opt to provide stepper arrows to let the user
>   increase and decrease the value using their mouse or by simply tapping
>   with a fingertip.

Comment: He said 'dot' is not allowed!

Comment: It does not prevent the mentioned unwanted characters.

Comment: @callback thanks for your attention. Great. I've edited a reply.

Comment: @BanafshehKhadem thanks for your attention. Cool. I've edited a reply.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you need:

```
[Test]
public void TestRegExDigitsOnly()
{
    var regEx = new Regex("^[0-9]*$");
    regEx.IsMatch("123").ShouldBeTrue();
    regEx.IsMatch("12.").ShouldBeFalse();
    regEx.IsMatch("1.3").ShouldBeFalse();
    regEx.IsMatch("abc").ShouldBeFalse();
}
```

Comment: this is allowing + character. I dont want + sign to be entered also. what should be regex in this case?